# Fireplace junction box wiring

Tags: fireplace

What size wire do I need to run to the fireplace junction box? The box was mounted but no wires running to it to make it hot.

Comment: Without details I would say that generally sized to the breaker, unless after a receptacle, then sized to load. How about some details?

Comment: What are you trying to connect to this junction box? Igniter for a gas fireplace? An electric heater/simulated fire? Lighting? Receptacles?